# How can I optimize a portfolio of projects in R with a series of constraints (like excel's solver)?

Tags: r, constraints, project, solver, portfolio

Sorry, it can sound like a basic question, but I haven't found any information that is suitable for my problem. The fact that I'm new in R contributes too.

I need to get an optium portfolio of projects in R with a series of constraints.

My portfolio of projects:

```
Return   Sector    Investment Project_name  
0.290    Solar     228376120  Solar1   
0.07     Solar     70021891   Solar2   
0.25     Wind      6467237    Eolico1  
0.3      Wind      417713440  Eolico2  
0.16     Wind      377494250  Eolico3  
0.28     Wind      230345712  Eolico4  
0.29     CGHPCHBIO 35476862   CGH1     
0.26     CGHPCHBIO 60671402   CGH2     
0.07     CGHPCHBIO 349544333  PCH1     
0.12     CGHPCHBIO 425442985  PCH2     
0.29     CGHPCHBIO 66292734   PCH3     
0.15     CGHPCHBIO 300677487  PCH4     
0.25     CGHPCHBIO 409144798  Biomassa1
0.19     CGHPCHBIO 184123496  Biomassa2
0.08     CGHPCHBIO 61835863   Biomassa3
```

My objective is:

- Maximize the "Return"

My constraints are:

- Limit of 916000000 for the total "Investment"
- "Solar Sector" can't exceed 60% of the total Investment;
- "Wind Sector" can't exceed 60% of the total Investment; and
- "CGHPCHBIO Sector" can't exceed 25% of the total Investment

I tried using the function optimize.portfolio from "PortfolioAnalysis, but it didn't work because I'm not dealing with stocks or bonds.

I would like to have a solution like the excel's solver, but in R.

Many thanks

Comment: It might help if you add a code snippet with your call to `PortfolioAnalysis::optimize.portfolio()` and the error message you saw, just so readers can see exactly how the thing failed.

Comment: When I try using `opt <- optimize.portfolio(teste, portfolio = port_spec, optimize_method = "ROI")`, I receive the following error: `Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'. 
In addition: Warning message:
In if (class(x) == "numeric") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: There are no covariances in your problem, so this would become a Linear Programming (LP) or Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) problem. If we can only do complete projects (not say 0.123 part of an investment project) you need binary variables and the problem becomes a MIP. LP/MIP solvers are readily available for R. I think portfolio optimization is a bit of a misnomer for your problem. It is more like an (investment) project selection problem.